# How to upload or share images on Flicker through php or Action script

Tags: php, apache-flex, share, flickr

i am developing an application in which user have the option to share images on different social sites like Facebook, twitter and Flickr.

I have done with Facebook and twitter, i upload image to my server and share the link on Facebook and Twitter.
with share link like

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=YOUR-IMAGE-PATH

this is working well.

But i don't have any idea how can i share my images on Flickr?
Please help me if anyone have done this or any idea of sharing images on Flickr through php or in action script.

Comment: Have you looked at the flickr api? http://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Comment: Yes. i have checked it and also checking in action script library for Flicker, but did not got any thing yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call Flicker [UPLOAD API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html) and need to send POST request from Flex 
using [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) for Flex see [Working with file upload and download](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=17_Networking_and_communications_7.html)

and you may find this blog [Flex and Flickr uploading](http://blog.engage-encore.com/index.php/2010/12/30/flex-and-flickr-uploading/) helpfull

Hopes that helps

Comment: Great excellent answer. Thanks Mr Imran. carry on good work. Wish you all the best.